# Search Youtube api using Proxy, per connection and not system wide

Tags: java, proxy, youtube, youtube-api, gdata-api

I have a Java code using youtube-api to search videos. Until now I was using the system configuration to set the proxy (http and https) and everything is working fine that way. But now I have a new requirement regarding the way we use proxy on the server. As we have other services running on the very same server, they asked me to not configure the proxy using system wide approach, because this affect all the services using JVM.

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", httpsProxyHost);
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", httpsProxyPort);
```

I want to do something like this:

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(clientID);

logger.info("proxyHost for youtube  updated :"+this.parameters.getProxyHost() );
logger.info("proxyPort for youtube  updated :"+this.parameters.getProxyPort() );


logger.info("before youtube constructor " );

service.setConnectTimeout(timeout); // millis
YouTubeQuery query = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(YOUTUBE_URL));
logger.info("afer youtube constructor " );
query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.VIEW_COUNT);
query.setFullTextQuery(textQuery);
query.setSafeSearch(YouTubeQuery.SafeSearch.NONE);
query.setMaxResults(maxResults);

VideoFeed videoFeed = service.query(query, VideoFeed.class);        
List<VideoEntry> videos = videoFeed.getEntries();
```